# How to create a ref using Typescript and styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, ref

I'm trying to add a **ref** to React component like this:

```
const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const [headerHeight, setHeaderHeight] = useState(0);

  const headerRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'null'
    setHeaderHeight(ref.current.clientHeight)
  });

  return (
    <Root>
      <Header ref={headerRef} />

      <div>other contents</div>             
    </Root>
  );
};
```

`<Header />` is a simple `React.FC`.
TS gives an error saying:

> Type '{ ref: RefObject; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
>     Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to give a ref typed for an input element to another React component. If you are trying to forward the ref to an element inside the `Header` component, you can use React's [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) function.